# Loading animation lagging while waiting for complex calculation to complete on front end

Tags: angular, animation

I'm building a puzzle game website for some friends, and occasionally a puzzle generation algorithm can take a decent amount of time to complete (4-5 seconds for more complex puzzles).

I built a service for displaying a loading animation when the application is currently not accepting user input, and it works beautifully for asynchronous api calls.

Example where is works perfectly:

```
this.loader.startLoadingAnimation(); // Indicate we are waiting
this.tunnel.startPuzzleTimer(GameID, Difficulty)
  .subscribe( (response) => {
    // Do something with response - removed for brevity
    this.loader.stopLoadingAnimation(); // Indicate we are done waiting
  });
```

It works exactly as you would expect, the animation plays at a beautifully high framerate, and disappears once the content is ready. However, I have issues when I try to use it like this:

```
this.loader.startLoadingAnimation(); // Indicate we are waiting
this.puzzleService.generatePuzzle(GameID, Difficulty); // Generate board, CPU intensive!!
this.loader.stopLoadingAnimation(); // Indicate we are done waiting
```

This time, the loading animation appears, but it runs at about 2 frames per second. Obviously this is caused by the expensive operation `generatePuzzle()`, but I was wondering if there is some way to perhaps utilize less CPU and generate the puzzle slower, and prioritize displaying a perfectly smooth loading animation.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: I'd try using a web worker